# Unable to Input the graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I am solving the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/SHOP/ in C++ but I am unable to figure out how to input the graph to furhter apply Dijkstra algorithm in it.
Here is the graph format-
4 3
X 1 S 3
4 2 X 4
X 1 D 2

First line indicated the columns & rows of the grid ,
"S" & "D" -indicates source and destination respetively 
Numbers -indicates the time required to pass that block,"X"-indicates the no entry zone.
HOw to convert the following graph in nodes and edges as required by DIjkstra algorithm.I don't know how to convert the map into a graph.

Comment: hm maybe this is wrong place to ask this kind of question (but what is I dont know..) try to change the question posting some code you have concentrating on single problem.. this is way too big and too theoretic..

Comment: also give us please more information about your problem... for example: can I go diagonal? so lets say from D over the 4 to S? or only vertical and horizontal? Next: do you want to work on the 2D array or notelist adj.matrix / list or like a linked list (nodes which are connected)...

Comment: btw: do you only want to know how to convert? or do you also have problems to program the dijkstra?

Comment: Are you stuck at this point reading in the map, reading the map into a graph, or writing a a graph into which you can read the map? You need to cut down the possibilities or the question will probably be locked as unclear or too broad.

Comment: No,one can't go diagonal,also I earlier I have coded standard problems in Adjacency list.I don't have a problem with Dijkstra ,only I know How to apply it with adjacency list or adjacency matrix

Comment: @user4581301 Edited

Comment: @Bing, you say *First line indicated the rows & columns of the grid* - are you sure it is not vice versa?  Because your example contradicts what you say *First line indicated the rows & columns of the grid*.

Comment: @BatCoder Sorry ,corrected

Comment: @Bing can you give us your structure how you want to fill it? make an example

Comment: Well in the form of Nodes -its adjacent edges,its weight form.Here is the solution which I found which I am unable to understand https://github.com/VitSalis/SPOJ/blob/master/SHOP/shop.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert. Just imagine that you are in some point (i,j). (I assume that you have four moves allowed from each square). Then, you can go to either (i + 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i - 1, j), (i, j - 1) if:

1) That index is inside the table
2) That index is not marked with X

So, you give the position of square S to your Dijkstra algorithm. And each time you add the new set of allowed squares to your data structure. Once your reach the position of D you print it.

Besides, this problem does not seem weighted to me so you can use a simple BFS as well using a queue. But if you want to use Dijkstra and going to different squares has different costs. The you use a priority queue instead of queue.
For example, you can use a set data structure like this:

```
 int dist[][]; // this contains the cost to get to some square
//dist is initialized with a large number

struct node{
    int i, j; //location
    node(int ii, int jj){
        i = ii;
        j = jj;
    }

    bool operator < (node &n)const{ //set in c++ will use this to sort
        if(dist[i][j] == dist[n.i][n.j]) return i < n.i || j < n.j; //this is necessary
        return dist[i][j] < dist[n.i][n.j];
    }
};

set <node> q;

int main(){
    //initialized dist with large number
    dist[S.i][S.j] = 0; //we start from source
    q.push(node(S.i, S.j));
    while(true){
        //pick the first element in set
        //this element has the smallest cost
        //update dist using this node if necessary
        //for every node that you update remove from q and add it again
        //this way the location of that node will be updated in q
        //if you see square 'D' you are done and you can print dist[D.i][D.j]
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks Can you tell why you overloaded '<' operator

Comment: It is overload because when you put nodes in a set data structure, the set needs to be able to compare two nodes. However, this is not needed if you have a set<int> or set<string>, ... because these primitive types can already be compared. The operator makes sure that the node with closest distance is always the first element in set. Otherwise, we can't find and remove the closest node in O(log n) since we may need to search the whole set in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert the matrix into nodes and edges.
You can make structure which contain (row number,column number ,time ) where time will represent how much time taken to reach this coordinate from source. now make a min heap of this structure with key as time. now extract element (initially source will be in min heap with time as 0) from min heap and push the adjacent elements into min heap(only those elements which are not visited and do not contain a X) set visited of extracted element true.Go on like this until extracted element is not destination.

Comment: Could you suggest how to push the adjacent elements in min-heap

Comment: There is very simple syntax of priority_queue in c++ stl. ( code: priority_queue<node,vector<node>,cmp> q; )where cmp is functor you can google it